# Why doesn't Silverlight's ItemsControl have an ItemContainerStyle property?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, itemscontrol

The title pretty much says it all.  I can roll my own, but given WPF has it, it's conspicuous by its absence.

Comment: Is `ItemTemplate` not enough?

Comment: no, I'm using a template selector for ItemTemplate and want to separate each element with a line, but not have to include the divide in each ItemTemplate

Answer (score 1):

I think exactly answered may only Silverlight developers, but they usually do not like to answer such questions. Silverlight is much stripped down version of WPF, it is done because [`MSDN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921107%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx):

> To keep `Silverlight` small and lightweight, some WPF and .NET Framework features are not available in `Silverlight`.

Why is removed `ItemContainerStyle`? Probably thought he was there in ListBox, so as an alternative you can use *`ListBox.ItemContainerStyle`*.

Although the developers could not just remove the `ItemContainerStyle` property from ItemsControl class, because this property is not in ListBox WPF, he inherits is from Selector class and Selector from `ItemsControl` like this:

```
[Localizability(LocalizationCategory.ListBox)]
[StyleTypedProperty(Property = "ItemContainerStyle", StyleTargetType = typeof(ListBoxItem))]
public class ListBox : Selector
{
   ...
}
```

This once again proves that it is a deliberate decision taken at the design stage of Silverlight.

In fact, many things in Silverlight and in WPF are implemented differently. Therefore, I advise you to see this links, but again, this is only a small (common) part of the difference:

[`Contrasting Silverlight and WPF`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921107%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx)

[`WPF Compatibility`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903925%28VS.95%29.aspx)

Comment: ListBox brings in the Selector semantics which I don't want. I do suspect it's deliberate, hence the question. <rhetorical>By rolling my own solution to workaround this am I introducing undesired behavior that the Silverlight design team identified</rhetorical>